# How do I obfuscate a JS file with nightmare.js library

Tags: node.js, encryption, obfuscation, nightmare

When I package the electron app on macOS I can never obfuscate the file with Nightmare because of its limitations. Would I need to re-write the whole library, or is there a way I can get around this?

Comment: What does Nightmare have to do with obfuscation?

Comment: On a related note, I'm having real hard time doing browser automation with UglifyJS...

Comment: Can you extract code that uses nightmare into its own file and ignore obfuscating those?

Comment: I was thinking this. But the nightmare code was the part I wanted to keep encrypted

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution. Absolutely unstable and untested, try at your own risk. And ofc, if you can find and fix the bugs that comes as side effect, feel free to share them :)

We are going to use a module called `pkg` to bundle up the script with `node`. Also for simplicity, we will use `npx`.

There were some side-effects but that was first time something worked with `electron` and `nightmare`.

Consider the following script,

```
const Nightmare = require("nightmare");
const nightmare = Nightmare({
  show: true
});

nightmare
  .goto("https://example.com")
  .title()
  .end()
  .then(console.log)
  .catch(error => {
    console.error(error);
  });
```

This is a simple script that says, go to `example.com` and give me the title.

Cool! Let's try using it thru `npx` and `pkg`. The code for that is,

```
npx pkg app.js --target 'host'
```

However, we got some nasty errors,

```
> Warning Cannot include file %1 into executable.
  The file must be distributed with executable as %2.
  node_modules/nightmare/lib/runner.js
  path-to-executable/nightmare/runner.js
> Warning Cannot include file %1 into executable.
  The file must be distributed with executable as %2.
  node_modules/nightmare/lib/frame-manager.js
...
```

etc etc. and the file wouldn't run.

```
Error: spawn /home/someone/Desktop/a/electron/dist/electron ENOENT
```

It cannot find the required files as they were not bundled. We will use `process.cwd()` to get those data which resides in relevant folder.

```
const nodeDir = process.cwd() + "/node_modules/"; // <- Get node modules folder 
const nightmareDir = nodeDir + "nightmare"; // <-- Get nightmarejs path
const electronDir = nodeDir + "electron"; // <-- Get electron path

const Nightmare = require(nightmareDir);
const electronPath = require(electronDir);

const nightmare = Nightmare({
  show: true,
  electronPath // <-- use the specific electron path
});

nightmare
  .goto("https://example.com")
  .title()
  .end()
  .then(console.log)
  .catch(error => {
    console.error(error);
  });
```

When I ran it, it showed me some more warning, but that's because I did not optimize the `process.cwd()` yet. Then I ran it and voila!

```
➜  a npx pkg app.js --target 'host'
> pkg@4.3.1
> Warning Cannot resolve 'nightmareDir'
  /home/someone/Desktop/a/app.js
  Dynamic require may fail at run time, because the requested file
  is unknown at compilation time and not included into executable.
  Use a string literal as an argument for 'require', or leave it
  as is and specify the resolved file name in 'scripts' option.
> Warning Cannot resolve 'electronDir'
  /home/someone/Desktop/a/app.js
  Dynamic require may fail at run time, because the requested file
  is unknown at compilation time and not included into executable.
  Use a string literal as an argument for 'require', or leave it
  as is and specify the resolved file name in 'scripts' option.
➜  a ./app
Example Domain // <-- Our sweet result :D 
➜  a
```

This can be improved and tweaked, but I'll leave that to you.